# Open Ethereum mining pool

Tags: mining

We are running a dbix pool on open eth pool was workin fine until 3 days ago and now it's out of sync with the network . I re installed the pool but still have the issue not syncing but has correct block height. I'm confused any help would be great thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you are running an other pool on the same node? I had the issue with my pool running eth and etc at the same time. Since I moved the etc pool to another server, everything works fine again.